# Angular - File download management component

Tags: angular, file, download

Are there any (open source) file download management component in Angular that can do pause or broken download/resume/concurrent sessions smartly?  I tried searching but couldn't find any..

Comment: you could expand your search beyond Angular-specific solutions and look for JavaScript libraries or general-purpose download managers that can be integrated with Angular. That might open up some options. I'm not aware of any.